# C pointer address changes on null pointer initialization in function

Tags: c

Disclaimer: I am new to C arrived here from other languages. What I observe breaks my head I do not even have a starting point to explain the observed behavior.

Scenario: Play around with a self-written stack implementation to get a feeling for the language and to compare different approaches.

Compiler in use:

```
gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.12) 5.4.0 20160609
```

Minimized code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct stack_entry
{
    struct stack_entry *next;
    int *item;
};

struct stack
{
    struct stack_entry *first;
};

void push_to_stack(struct stack *s_ptr, int *item)
{
    struct stack_entry new_entry = {.next = s_ptr->first, .item = item};
    s_ptr->first = &new_entry;
    printf("item_address@push_to_stack %p\n", s_ptr->first->item);
}

void pop_from_stack(struct stack *s_ptr)
{
    printf("item_address@pop_from_stack %p\n", s_ptr->first->item);
    int* result = NULL; 
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n--stack test--\n");
    struct stack s = {};
    struct stack *s_ptr = &s;
    int value = 42;

    push_to_stack(s_ptr, &value);
    printf("item_address@main: %p\n", s_ptr->first->item);
    pop_from_stack(s_ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Unexpected output:

```
--stack test--
item_address@push_to_stack 0x7fffa759b67c
item_address@main: 0x7fffa759b67c
item_address@pop_from_stack 0x7fffa759b680
```

As one observes the `item_address@pop_from_stack` differs for some reason. I expect the output:

```
--stack test--
item_address@push_to_stack 0x7ffdc30ee19c
item_address@main: 0x7ffdc30ee19c
item_address@pop_from_stack 0x7ffdc30ee19c
```

To receive the expected output I need to remove the pointer declaration+initialization. In case I leave it in place the unexpected output occurs. So the following does the change:

```
// int* result = NULL;
```

But why? This totally puzzles me.

Comment: `s_ptr->first = &new_entry;` That's a problem because `new_entry` is a local variable. It's not valid outside the function.

Comment: In `push_to_stack` you define `new_entry` as a *local* variable. Local (non-static) variables only have a life-time of the function they're defined in. Once the function returns those variables cease to exist, and all pointers to them becomes invalid. This should be mentioned in just about any decent book, tutorial or class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will trigger undefined behavior later on:

```
struct stack_entry new_entry = {.next = s_ptr->first, .item = item};
s_ptr->first = &new_entry;
```

because `new_entry` will die when `push_to_stack()` ends.

> But why? This totally puzzles me.

When compiled without optimizations, that line is likely making the compiler allocate space for `result` in the `pop_from_stack()` frame. Such  a thing will make the behavior of the program change due to the undefined behavior shown above.

Comment: thanks to all. So if I understand correctly by accident the address remains stable when control flow is back to the main due to the fact that there is no necessity to clean the stack to give space for new variables to come. But this becomes enforced when a new context requires creation due to a local variable within the code block. So that the address changes...

Comment: @s10z To know exactly we'd need to examine the generated assembly in your particular platform, but yes, anything that changes the layout of the stack frames will give you different behavior. Different platforms, compilers and flags will also show differences.